# How to stop Bootstrap 4 slider images from moving position on slide when background-attachment:fixed applied? (Parallax effect)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am attempting to add a Parallax scrolling effect to my Bootstrap 4 slider. However, when the slider changes to the next image, the image has to move into place after it has been changed. How do I stop this from happening?

```css
.customOverlayText {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item {
  height: 500px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-color: black;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.general {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  padding-left: 200px;
  padding-right: 200px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1146px) {
  .general {
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel slide" data-pause="false" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="customOverlayText d-flex h-100 align-items-center justify-content-center">
    <center>Overlay</center>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-inner text-center">
    <div class="carousel-item active" style="background-image:url(http://coopertimewell.com/testing/images/slider/1.jpg);"></div>
    <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image:url(http://coopertimewell.com/testing/images/slider/2.jpg);"></div>
    <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image:url(http://coopertimewell.com/testing/images/slider/3.jpg);"></div>
    <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image:url(http://coopertimewell.com/testing/images/slider/4.jpg);"></div>
    <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image:url(http://coopertimewell.com/testing/images/slider/5.jpg);"></div>
    <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image:url(http://coopertimewell.com/testing/images/slider/6.jpg);"></div>
    <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image:url(http://coopertimewell.com/testing/images/slider/7.jpg);"></div>
    <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image:url(http://coopertimewell.com/testing/images/slider/8.jpg);"></div>
    <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image:url(http://coopertimewell.com/testing/images/slider/9.jpg);"></div>
    <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image:url(http://coopertimewell.com/testing/images/slider/10.jpg);"></div>
    <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image:url(http://coopertimewell.com/testing/images/slider/11.jpg);"></div>
    <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image:url(http://coopertimewell.com/testing/images/slider/12.jpg);"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<center>
  <div class="general" id="redGeneral">
    <h2>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Nullam eget felis eget nunc lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus. Dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit pellentesque habitant
      morbi tristique. Nisl pretium fusce id velit ut tortor pretium viverra. Velit dignissim sodales ut eu sem integer vitae justo eget. Scelerisque viverra mauris in aliquam sem. Nunc consequat interdum varius sit amet. Fames ac turpis egestas sed tempus
      urna. At volutpat diam ut venenatis tellus in metus. Sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit pellentesque habitant morbi tristique. Eget mauris pharetra et ultrices neque ornare. Id aliquet risus feugiat in ante metus dictum. Accumsan in nisl nisi
      scelerisque eu ultrices vitae auctor eu. Etiam dignissim diam quis enim lobortis scelerisque fermentum. Consectetur lorem donec massa sapien faucibus et. Mauris pharetra et ultrices neque ornare aenean. Amet nisl purus in mollis nunc sed id.</h2>
  </div>
```

Also, am I able to add the text overlay onto the Parallax scrolling effect?

Answer (score 0):

A parallax effect normally requires at least two layers moving at different speeds. I don't think the BS carousel is designed to do this.
Also images are usually added with the

```
<img src="">
```

attribute rather than using a background image to maintain the perspective ratio.
If you want to proceed with the effect you are trying to achieve then could you add some sort of image explanation or example you have seen? I think this would be difficult using the BS framework (lots of overrides).
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/
With your question could you add a complete code example with your question? Edit it then use the (<> icon).